# @Cacheable in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching, interceptor

Spring framework has a very nice `@Cacheable` annotation. Is there a way to reproduce this functionality in a Java EE application by using `@Interceptors` and ehCache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is JSR-107, standardising a Java Cache API. This was scheduled to be included in Java EE 7, but will not make it in time according to the latest announcements.

Anyway, I tried the [reference implementation](https://github.com/jsr107) in Dec. 2012, and it worked fine for me after applying two minor pull requests and building it locally. I didn't try it with ehCache, though.

There are annotations that work with CDI.